# Non-latching relay as an "AND" gate

Tags: relay

I have a situation where I have two inputs, A and B. These inputs control a device. Input A acts as a direction select and Input B acts as a "GO" command. I only want the device to "GO" if I know that input A is connected via the relay.

My thought is to use the circuit below. I know it won't be able to check the presence of input A, but will it guarantee that whenever the relay closes, both Input A and input B will be connected? Or is there a better way to do this?

Without knowing the internals have a non-latching relay, is it possible that one input closes while the other doesn't? Presumably it can happen if the contact gets dirty?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUml8N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: this appears to be an X-Y problem ..... you are trying to get help with what you consider to be a solution to your problem even though the solution may be misguided (not saying that it actually is misguided) .... please present the original problem, not the your solution to the original problem

Answer (score 1):

> Without knowing the internals have a non-latching relay, is it possible that one input closes while the other doesn't? Presumably it can happen if the contact gets dirty?

No, contacts A and B are not guaranteed to be in the same position, unless you use ['mechanically linked' or 'force-guided' contacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Force-guided_contacts_relay). These relays are usually used in safety related applications.

(Without having the detail of your application this is hard to answer, but you will probably need two relays to make a sequence.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you feed to input A something which has a polarity or other property to make difference between the directions. If that signal can pull a relay in both direction cases, use it to gate the GO-signal.